# removing data from SQL table using python

Tags: python, loops

I'm trying to achieve something with a function I have.
so as you can see here:

[image]

this is an SQL table with data. when I upload 2 docs I get it on doc0 and doc1 and all the others are null.
but what I want to do is if I upload only 2 docs the rest will be removed completely from the SQL table.

this is my code:

```
def submit_quality_dept_application(request, application_id):
n = int(request.data['length'])
application = Application.objects.get(id=application_id)
application_state = application.application_state
teaching_feedback = request.FILES['teaching-feedback']
application_state['teaching_feedback'] = teaching_feedback.name
now = datetime.now()
dt_string = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
application_state['edited_time'] = dt_string
for i in range(5):
    application_state[f'doc{i}'] = None
for i in range(n):
    doc = request.FILES[f'doc{i}']
    application_state[f'doc{i}'] = doc.name
    copy_to_application_directory(doc, application.id)
copy_to_application_directory(teaching_feedback, application.id)
ApplicationStep.objects.update_or_create(
    application=application, step_name=Step.STEP_7
)
Application.objects.filter(id=application_id).update(application_state=application_state)
return Response(n, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

what should I do to achieve it?
thank you so much for your help!

Comment: does anyone have an idea?